# Memory allocation errors in C++ code

Tags: c++

I am getting all kinds of memory errors when testing the code in the header file. Please help me by letting me know what's wrong in the same. Thank you!

The code in question is the one in the code block below. It has comments so its pretty self explanatory.

Thank you very much for your help!!!

```
#include <algorithm>

class sorted_sc_array {
public:
    sorted_sc_array() : size_(0), ptr_(nullptr), arr_len(1000) { 
        ptr_ = new signed char[arr_len];
    }

    ~sorted_sc_array() { delete[] ptr_; }

    // IMPLEMENT ME (DONE!!!! SOME EDITS REQD)
    sorted_sc_array(const sorted_sc_array& A) {this->size_ = A.size_; this->ptr_ = A.ptr_; /* change this to match the definition of operator=() function */}

    // IMPLEMENT  ME (DONE!!!!)
    sorted_sc_array& operator=(const sorted_sc_array& A) {
        if (this == &A) return *this;
        delete[] ptr_;
        size_ = A.size_;
        if (size_ == 0) ptr_ = nullptr;
        else {
            ptr_ = new signed char[size_];
            std::copy(A.ptr_, A.ptr_ + size_, ptr_);
        }
        return *this;
    }

    // RETURNS SIZE OF THE ARRAY (i.e. HOW MANY ELEMENTS IT STORES)
    int size() const { return size_; }

    // RETURNS RAW POINTER TO THE ACTUAL DATA, CAN BE INVOKED AT ANY TIME
    const signed char* data() const { return ptr_; }

    // IMPLEMENT ME: AFTER INSERT COMPLETES THE ARRAY MUST BE IN ASCENDING ORDER (TBD!!!)
    void insert(signed char c) { 
        if (size_ < arr_len) {
            ptr_[size_++] = c;
            std::sort(ptr_, ptr_ + size_);
        }

        else {
            int arr_len_new = arr_len*2;
            ptr_ = new signed char[arr_len_new];
            std::copy(ptr_, ptr_ + size_, ptr_);

            ptr_[size_++] = c;
            std::sort(ptr_, ptr_ + size_);
        }

        // maybe use std::sort (myvector.begin(), myvector.end());
        // if inefficient, use binary insertion
    }

private:
    int size_;         // size of the array
    signed char* ptr_; // pointer to the array
    unsigned int arr_len; // dynamic mem alloc for array    
}; // class sorted_sc_array
```

Comment: What errors are you getting? What have you learned by running the code in a debugger?

Comment: "all kinds of memory errors" is too much generic. Specify it better

Comment: The right tool to solve such problems is your debugger. You should step through your code line-by-line *before* asking on Stack Overflow. For more help, please read [How to debug small programs (by Eric Lippert)](https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/). At a minimum, you should \[edit] your question to include a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) example that reproduces your problem, along with the observations you made in the debugger.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `insert()` function has a number of errors when it's growing the array.

1. It doesn't update `arr_len` with the new length.
2. It's reassigning `ptr_` with the new array before it has copied the values from the old array, and then it's copying the array to itself. You need to use a temporary variable for this.
3. It never frees the old array.

This fixes those problems:

```
void insert(signed char c) { 
    if (size_ < arr_len) {
        ptr_[size_++] = c;
        std::sort(ptr_, ptr_ + size_);
    }

    else {
        arr_len = arr_len*2;
        signed char *ptr_new = new signed char[arr_len];
        std::copy(ptr_, ptr_ + size_, ptr_new);
        delete[] ptr_;
        ptr_ = ptr_new;
        ptr_[size_++] = c;
        std::sort(ptr_, ptr_ + size_);
    }
```

Comment: Thank you, I will work on fixing those. However, could you also tell me what the specific error means? My compiler says the following: "corrupted double- linked list: 0x0000....aba110"

Comment: Something in your program is causing undefined behavior and corrupting the heap memory. Maybe the problem OlafDietsche mentioned in his answer.

Comment: Thank you SO much for your help. May I ask just one last question? What would be the most efficient way to implement the insert method in my program? Your suggestions have enabled my program to run successfully, however, I need to improve its efficiency. Thank you once again for the help!

Comment: Your `insert` method is reasonably efficient.

Answer (score 0):

You don't specify, what concrete errors you get. Although, most likely your problems come from ignoring the `arr_len` member. You copy `size_` and allocate memory properly, but you ignore `arr_len` when initializing or copying. This produces problems later on, when you access and compare the uninitialized `arr_len`.

Comment: The constructor initializes `arr_len` to 1000.

Comment: Yes, in the *default* constructor, but not in the copy constructor. And it is ignored in `operator=`.